# Slicing a numpy array along a dynamically specified axis

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to dynamically slice a numpy array along a specific axis. Given this:

```
axis = 2
start = 5
end = 10
```

I want to achieve the same result as this:

```
# m is some matrix
m[:,:,5:10]
```

Using something like this:

```
slc = tuple(:,) * len(m.shape)
slc[axis] = slice(start,end)
m[slc]
```

But the `:` values can't be put in a tuple, so I can't figure out how to build the slice.

Comment: What does `m` look like?

Comment: @MrAlias It doesn't matter. The question is how to build a slice dynamically.

Comment: linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36576531

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think one way would be to use `slice(None)`:

```
>>> m = np.arange(2*3*5).reshape((2,3,5))
>>> axis, start, end = 2, 1, 3
>>> target = m[:, :, 1:3]
>>> target
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 6,  7],
        [11, 12]],

       [[16, 17],
        [21, 22],
        [26, 27]]])
>>> slc = [slice(None)] * len(m.shape)
>>> slc[axis] = slice(start, end)
>>> np.allclose(m[slc], target)
True
```

I have a vague feeling I've used a function for this before, but I can't seem to find it now..

Comment: Thanks-- this solves the problem. `slice(None)` is apparently equivalent to `:`.

Comment: Great solution, although indexing with a list as in `m[slc]` is now deprecated in Numpy and throws a `FutureWarning`. The suggested fix in that `FutureWarning` is to convert the list to a tuple instead, which would be `m[tuple(slc)]`.

Comment: Nice. This answer also works when pulling from a netCDF Dataset using `netCDF4` where `numpy.take` isn't available.

Comment: Instead of `len(m.shape)`, use `m.ndim`.

Answer (score 68):

As it was not mentioned clearly enough (and i was looking for it too):

an equivalent to:

```
a = my_array[:, :, :, 8]
b = my_array[:, :, :, 2:7]
```

is:

```
a = my_array.take(indices=8, axis=3)
b = my_array.take(indices=range(2, 7), axis=3)
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Using np.take creates a new array that copies data from the original array.  This may not be something you want (additional memory usage can be significant for large arrays)

Comment: Does this answer support negative indices, e.g. `slice(1, -1)`?

Comment: Yes, this is an elegant solution in case you would copy the data anyways. And yes, it supports negative indices. However, when you just need a view, the memory and speed costs can be significant. E.g. taking out one channel from a 1000x1000 RGB image (on my machine) takes 6.4ms as opposed to 198ns when using a slice. That means in this particular case np.take was 32 million times slower (measured with %timeit).

Answer (score 18):

This is *very* late to the party, but I have an alternate slicing function that performs slightly better than those from the other answers:

```
def array_slice(a, axis, start, end, step=1):
    return a[(slice(None),) * (axis % a.ndim) + (slice(start, end, step),)]
```

---

Here's a code testing each answer.  Each version is labeled with the name of the user who posted the answer:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def answer_dms(a, axis, start, end, step=1):
    slc = [slice(None)] * len(a.shape)
    slc[axis] = slice(start, end, step)
    return a[slc]

def answer_smiglo(a, axis, start, end, step=1):
    return a.take(indices=range(start, end, step), axis=axis)

def answer_eelkespaak(a, axis, start, end, step=1):
    sl = [slice(None)] * m.ndim
    sl[axis] = slice(start, end, step)
    return a[tuple(sl)]

def answer_clemisch(a, axis, start, end, step=1):
    a = np.moveaxis(a, axis, 0)
    a = a[start:end:step]
    return np.moveaxis(a, 0, axis)

def answer_leland(a, axis, start, end, step=1):
    return a[(slice(None),) * (axis % a.ndim) + (slice(start, end, step),)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = np.arange(2*3*5).reshape((2,3,5))
    axis, start, end = 2, 1, 3
    target = m[:, :, 1:3]
    for answer in (answer_dms, answer_smiglo, answer_eelkespaak,
                   answer_clemisch, answer_leland):
        print(answer.__name__)
        m_copy = m.copy()
        m_slice = answer(m_copy, axis, start, end)
        c = np.allclose(target, m_slice)
        print('correct: %s' %c)
        t = timeit('answer(m, axis, start, end)',
                   setup='from __main__ import answer, m, axis, start, end')
        print('time:    %s' %t)
        try:
            m_slice[0,0,0] = 42
        except:
            print('method:  view_only')
        finally:
            if np.allclose(m, m_copy):
                print('method:  copy')
            else:
                print('method:  in_place')
        print('')
```

Here are the results:

```
answer_dms

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\leland.hepworth\test_dynamic_slicing.py", line 7
    return a[slc]
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is 
deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be 
interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an 
error or a different result.
correct: True
time:    2.2048302
method:  in_place

answer_smiglo
correct: True
time:    5.9013344
method:  copy

answer_eelkespaak
correct: True
time:    1.1219435999999998
method:  in_place

answer_clemisch
correct: True
time:    13.707583699999999
method:  in_place

answer_leland
correct: True
time:    0.9781496999999995
method:  in_place
```

- [DSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24399139/12808884) includes a few suggestions for improvement in the comments.
- [EelkeSpaak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37729566/12808884) applies those improvements, which avoids the warning and is quicker.
- [Śmigło's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859801/12808884) involving [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) gives worse results, and while it is not view-only, it does create a copy.
- [clemisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840428/12808884) involving [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) takes the longest time to complete, but it surprisingly references back to the previous array's memory location.
- My answer removes the need for the intermediary slicing list.  It also uses a shorter slicing index when the slicing axis is toward the beginning.  This gives the quickest results, with additional improvements as axis is closer to 0.

I also added a `step` parameter to each version, in case that is something you need.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting comparison! I somehow saw this only now. I am surprised that `moveaxis` is so much slower, because I thought it did the same thing as the list of `slice` objects. Definitely good to know!

Comment: Your function does not support `axis=-1`, making `answer_eelkespaak` the best option.

Answer (score 17):

This is a bit late to the party, but the default Numpy way to do this is [`numpy.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html). However, that one *always* copies data (since it supports fancy indexing, it always assumes this is possible). To avoid that (in many cases you will want a *view* of the data, not a copy), fallback to the `slice(None)` option already mentioned in the other answer, possibly wrapping it in a nice function:

```
def simple_slice(arr, inds, axis):
    # this does the same as np.take() except only supports simple slicing, not
    # advanced indexing, and thus is much faster
    sl = [slice(None)] * arr.ndim
    sl[axis] = inds
    return arr[tuple(sl)]
```

Comment: If would be helpful if you could clarify what data type you expect the `inds` parameter is.

Answer (score 8):

There is an elegant way to access an arbitrary axis `n` of array `x`: Use [`numpy.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)¹ to move the axis of interest to the front.

```py
x_move = np.moveaxis(x, n, 0)  # move n-th axis to front
x_move[start:end]              # access n-th axis
```

The catch is that you likely have to apply `moveaxis` on other arrays you use with the output of `x_move[start:end]` to keep axis order consistent. The array `x_move` is only a view, so every change you make to its front axis corresponds to a change of `x` in the `n`-th axis (i.e. you can read/write to `x_move`).

---

<sub>1) You could also use [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to not worry about the order of `n` and `0`, contrary to `moveaxis(x, n, 0)`. I prefer `moveaxis` over `swapaxes` because it only alters the order concerning `n`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

this is *very very* late indeed! But I got [Leland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64436208/1732466) and expanded it so it works with multiple axis and slice arguments. Here is the verbose version of the function

```
from numpy import *

def slicer(a, axis=None, slices=None):
    if not hasattr(axis, '__iter__'):
        axis = [axis]
    if not hasattr(slices, '__iter__') or len(slices) != len(axis):
        slices = [slices]
    slices = [ sl if isinstance(sl,slice) else slice(*sl) for sl in slices ]
    mask = []
    fixed_axis = array(axis) % a.ndim
    case = dict(zip(fixed_axis, slices))
    for dim, size in enumerate(a.shape):
        mask.append( case[dim] if dim in fixed_axis else slice(None) )
    return a[tuple(mask)]
```

it works for variable amount of axes and with tuples of slices as input

```
>>> a = array( range(10**4) ).reshape(10,10,10,10)
>>> slicer( a, -2, (1,3) ).shape
(10, 10, 2, 10)
>>> slicer( a, axis=(-1,-2,0), slices=((3,), s_[:5], slice(3,None)) ).shape
(7, 10, 5, 3)
```

---

a slightly more compact version

```
def slicer2(a, axis=None, slices=None):
    ensure_iter = lambda l: l if hasattr(l, '__iter__') else [l]
    axis = array(ensure_iter(axis)) % a.ndim
    if len(ensure_iter(slices)) != len(axis):
        slices = [slices]
    slice_selector = dict(zip(axis, [ sl if isinstance(sl,slice) else slice(*sl) for sl in ensure_iter(slices) ]))
    element = lambda dim_: slice_selector[dim_] if dim_ in slice_selector.keys() else slice(None)
    return a[( element(dim) for dim in range(a.ndim) )]
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw no comments which mentioned the `Ellipsis` object and so wanted to include another, just slightly different solution, which works for positive and negative axes. This solution has a function which generates the slice along the desired dimension.

The main reason I include this is to make sure that someone who learns about dynamic slicing also learns about using ellipsis.

```
def _slice_along_axis(slice_inds,axis=-1):
    '''
    Returns a slice such that the 1d slice provided by slice_inds, slices along the dimension provided.
    '''
    from_end=False
    if axis<0: # choosing axis at the end
        from_end = True
        axis = -1-axis
    explicit_inds_slice = axis*(slice(None),) 
    if from_end:
        return (Ellipsis,slice_inds) + explicit_inds_slice
    else:
        return  explicit_inds_slice + (slice_inds,)
```

In order to use this, one can simply call the slice as usual.
Examples:

```
a = my_array[:, :, :, 8]
b = my_array[:, :, :, 2:7]
c = my_array[...,3] # (equivalent to my_array.take(axis=-1,indices=3)
```

are equivalent to

```
a = my_array[_slice_along_axis(8,axis=3)]
b = my_array[_slice_along_axis(slice(2,7),axis=3)]
c = my_array[_slice_along_axis(3,axis=-1)]
```

One advantage of this approach is that the slice can be generated once and then used in other arrays, even if the number of dimensions in the other arrays is not the same (case of a negative axis).