# tuple as index in multidimensional array together with slicing

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a 3-dimensional array `A`, and I need to access `A[:,1,1]` through the tuple `x=[1,1]`.
Something like this:

```
x = [1,1]
A[:,*x]
```

However, doing that I get a syntax error. I would love to be able to access the elements of `A[:,1,1]` using the variable `x`, how can I do that?

Thank you!

---

Second question:

How to do the same but instead of slicing `:` do it with a boolean array. For example if `t` is an array of booleans, obtain `A[t, *x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 3, 2))
print(A)

x = [1, 1]
print(A[(slice(None), *x)])
```

You can use `slice(None)` instead of `:` to build a tuple of slices. The tuple environment allows for value unpacking with the * operator.

Output:

```
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]]

[3 9]
```

---

To verify it matches:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 3, 2))
x = [1, 1]
s = (slice(None), *x)
print(np.allclose(A[s], A[:, 1, 1]))  # True
```

*This is a modification of answers found here: [Slicing a numpy array along a dynamically specified axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398708/15497888)

---

Edit to reflect edit on question and comment:

To clarify, you can unpack *any* iterable you like in the tuple environment. The * operator functions *normally* in within the tuple. Order your elements however you like. Mix in different iterables, types, `slice(None)`, how ever you want to build your slices, as long as you end up with a valid sequence of values, it will behave as expected.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 3, 2))
t = [True, False]
x = [1, 1]
print(np.allclose(A[(*t, *x)], A[True, False, 1, 1]))  # True
```

You can also add full lists as well in the tuple:

```py
print(np.allclose(A[(t, *x)], A[[True, False], 1, 1]))  # True
```

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question:
How would you do if instead of a slice `:` I have an array of booleans as first argument?
For example if I have `t = [False, True]` and I want `A[t, *x]`

Comment: Answer is updated to include this as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `slice(None)` instead of `:`, So

```py
y = tuple([slice[None]] + x)
A[y]
```

is what you need.

Comment: because I want it more general. I am writing a flexible program that might well have `A` with more than three dimensions, and so `x` would have more dimensions too