# Numpy Slicing: equivalence of [: , 2:3, 1] and slice() notation

Tags: python, numpy

I am failing to understand how the function slice() relates to the usual Numpy indexing notation.

```
test = np.random.rand(4,4,4)
test[:,0:1,2]
>>> array([[0.73897606],
         [0.68005618],
         [0.32831257],
         [0.36882484]])
```

but I cannot see what is about to go on now

```
test[slice(None),slice(0,1),slice(2,3)]
>>>> array([[[0.73897606]],

           [[0.68005618]],

           [[0.32831257]],

           [[0.36882484]]])
```

Some experiments seem to confirm that `slice(None)` is equivalent to `:`,  `slice(0,1)` is equivalent to `0:1`, but `slice(2,3)` is equivalent to `2`, as an index.

How to describe the `[:,0:1,2]` slicing using the `slice()` function?

Could somebody please give us a hint? I also do not get where the shape of the second output comes from, many thanks

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL BACKGROUND**

What I would like to be able to do is dynamically slice an array, given an input.
For example, given an array `S` with shape (10,10,10,10), the user might select two variables to plot over, keeping the other two fixed at a selected location.
For example, (surface)plot the first and third, keeping the second and fourth at indeces say (2,3).
I can pass then the array `S[:,2,:,3]`.

Following the answer in [Dynamically slice an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398708/slicing-a-numpy-array-along-a-dynamically-specified-axis), I though I would have something like

```
axis_to_plot_1 = 0
axis_to_plot_2 = 2
axis_to_slice_1 = 1
index_to_consider_1 = 2
axis_to_slice_2 = 3
index_to_consider_2 = 3
slc = [slice(None)] * len(S.shape)
slc[axis_to_slice_1] = slice(index_to_consider_1, index_to_consider_1 +1)
slc[axis_to_slice_2] = slice(index_to_consider_2, index_to_consider_2+1)
```

this would solve my issue, I could `slice()` for both the `:` (variable to consider when plotting) and "i" indexing cases (section on remaining dimensions).

How is the above dynamical slicing over two axes best implemented, any ideas please?

Comment: You said: "slice(2,3) is equivalent to 2". That's not true. Carefully check the number of dimensions in `test[slice(2, 3)]` versus `test[2]`. `slice(2, 3)` is still equivalent to `2:3`, which amounts to just one element (along that axis), but in a list, while `2` result in one element on its own.

Comment: There is no equivalent slice for a simple integer index: `2` is just two; don't use `slice()`.

Comment: thanks a lot, got really fooled on this one. I added some background above of what I was trying to achieve, and why I tried to use slice for a simple integer index.

Comment: `np.s_` goes the other direction: `np.s_[:4,2:3,2]` returns `(slice(None, 4, None), slice(2, 3, None), 2)`.  So `a:b:c` has a `slice(a,b,c)` equivalent.  But scalar `2` is not expressible as a `slice`.  In `s_`, it's actually the python interpreter that's parsing the 'a:b:c', and creating the `slice` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not equivalent. `2` is not a slice but an index. A slice will keep the number of dimensions, while an index will remove one.

The equivalence would be:

```
test[:, 0:1, [2]]
```

Output:

```
array([[[0.42475402]],

       [[0.48023367]],

       [[0.95256927]],

       [[0.25481038]]])
```

Comment: thanks for this, I got badly fooled. I added above some background about what is that I am trying to achieve, if you could have a look that would be great. IF there is no way to use ```slice()``` to reproduce an index, my idea described above fails, thanks a lot

Comment: @user37292 as slicing is keeping the dimensions, just make your plotting code use the original dimensions. Otherwise, you can always [`squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) the array to remove the axes of length one.